# How to parse json array with indexes from Yahoo Api

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Given this response from a Yahoo API, I am trying to parse the players out of it using Newtonsoft.Json and ASP.NET / C#.  I would also like to check the value of `count` at the end.

```
{
  "fantasy_content": {
    "xml:lang": "en-US",
    "yahoo:uri": "/fantasy/v2/game/nfl/players",
    "game": [
      {
        "game_key": "390",
        "game_id": "390",
        "name": "Football",
        "code": "nfl",
        "type": "full",
        "url": "https://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1",
        "season": "2019",
        "is_registration_over": 0,
        "is_game_over": 0,
        "is_offseason": 0
      },
      {
        "players": {
          "0": {
            "player": [
              [
                {
                  "player_key": "390.p.30972"
                },
                {
                  "player_id": "30972"
                },
                {
                  "name": {
                    "full": "Saquon Barkley",
                    "first": "Saquon",
                    "last": "Barkley",
                    "ascii_first": "Saquon",
                    "ascii_last": "Barkley"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "editorial_player_key": "nfl.p.30972"
                },
                {
                  "editorial_team_key": "nfl.t.19"
                },
                {
                  "editorial_team_full_name": "New York Giants"
                },
                {
                  "editorial_team_abbr": "NYG"
                },
                {
                  "bye_weeks": {
                    "week": "11"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "uniform_number": "26"
                },
                {
                  "display_position": "RB"
                },
                {
                  "headshot": {
                    "url": "https://s.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/RtPm7fdFHthz1._DrpkAqA--~C/YXBwaWQ9eXNwb3J0cztjaD0yMzM2O2NyPTE7Y3c9MTc5MDtkeD04NTc7ZHk9MDtmaT11bGNyb3A7aD02MDtxPTEwMDt3PTQ2/https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/nfl_cutout/players_l/09242018/30972.png",
                    "size": "small"
                  },
                  "image_url": "https://s.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/RtPm7fdFHthz1._DrpkAqA--~C/YXBwaWQ9eXNwb3J0cztjaD0yMzM2O2NyPTE7Y3c9MTc5MDtkeD04NTc7ZHk9MDtmaT11bGNyb3A7aD02MDtxPTEwMDt3PTQ2/https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/nfl_cutout/players_l/09242018/30972.png"
                },
                {
                  "is_undroppable": "0"
                },
                {
                  "position_type": "O"
                },
                [],
                {
                  "eligible_positions": [
                    {
                      "position": "RB"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                [],
                [],
                []
              ]
            ]
          },
          "1": {
            "player": [
              [
                {
                  "player_key": "390.p.29238"
                },
                {
                  "player_id": "29238"
                },
                {
                  "name": {
                    "full": "Ezekiel Elliott",
                    "first": "Ezekiel",
                    "last": "Elliott",
                    "ascii_first": "Ezekiel",
                    "ascii_last": "Elliott"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "editorial_player_key": "nfl.p.29238"
                },
                {
                  "editorial_team_key": "nfl.t.6"
                },
                {
                  "editorial_team_full_name": "Dallas Cowboys"
                },
                {
                  "editorial_team_abbr": "Dal"
                },
                {
                  "bye_weeks": {
                    "week": "8"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "uniform_number": "21"
                },
                {
                  "display_position": "RB"
                },
                {
                  "headshot": {
                    "url": "https://s.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/.0ocryeNkGmnFWlYOhT4hw--~C/YXBwaWQ9eXNwb3J0cztjaD0yMzM2O2NyPTE7Y3c9MTc5MDtkeD04NTc7ZHk9MDtmaT11bGNyb3A7aD02MDtxPTEwMDt3PTQ2/https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/nfl_cutout/players_l/09272018/29238.png",
                    "size": "small"
                  },
                  "image_url": "https://s.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/.0ocryeNkGmnFWlYOhT4hw--~C/YXBwaWQ9eXNwb3J0cztjaD0yMzM2O2NyPTE7Y3c9MTc5MDtkeD04NTc7ZHk9MDtmaT11bGNyb3A7aD02MDtxPTEwMDt3PTQ2/https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/nfl_cutout/players_l/09272018/29238.png"
                },
                {
                  "is_undroppable": "0"
                },
                {
                  "position_type": "O"
                },
                [],
                {
                  "eligible_positions": [
                    {
                      "position": "RB"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                [],
                [],
                []
              ]
            ]
          },
          "2": {
            "player": [
              [
                {
                  "player_key": "390.p.30180"
                },
                {
                  "player_id": "30180"
                },
                {
                  "name": {
                    "full": "Alvin Kamara",
                    "first": "Alvin",
                    "last": "Kamara",
                    "ascii_first": "Alvin",
                    "ascii_last": "Kamara"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "editorial_player_key": "nfl.p.30180"
                },
                {
                  "editorial_team_key": "nfl.t.18"
                },
                {
                  "editorial_team_full_name": "New Orleans Saints"
                },
                {
                  "editorial_team_abbr": "NO"
                },
                {
                  "bye_weeks": {
                    "week": "9"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "uniform_number": "41"
                },
                {
                  "display_position": "RB"
                },
                {
                  "headshot": {
                    "url": "https://s.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/loANJKjPdmUu1gM1jyKK1A--~C/YXBwaWQ9eXNwb3J0cztjaD0yMzM2O2NyPTE7Y3c9MTc5MDtkeD04NTc7ZHk9MDtmaT11bGNyb3A7aD02MDtxPTEwMDt3PTQ2/https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/nfl_cutout/players_l/08252018/30180.png",
                    "size": "small"
                  },
                  "image_url": "https://s.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/loANJKjPdmUu1gM1jyKK1A--~C/YXBwaWQ9eXNwb3J0cztjaD0yMzM2O2NyPTE7Y3c9MTc5MDtkeD04NTc7ZHk9MDtmaT11bGNyb3A7aD02MDtxPTEwMDt3PTQ2/https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/nfl_cutout/players_l/08252018/30180.png"
                },
                {
                  "is_undroppable": "0"
                },
                {
                  "position_type": "O"
                },
                [],
                {
                  "eligible_positions": [
                    {
                      "position": "RB"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                [],
                [],
                []
              ]
            ]
          },
          "count": 3
        }
      }
    ],
    "time": "181.84494972229ms",
    "copyright": "Data provided by Yahoo! and STATS, LLC",
    "refresh_rate": "60"
  }
}
```

Two things are throwing me off.

1. `game` is an array which seems strange, and
2. the players each have an index before them, like

   `0: { player: {  //dah dah dah  }`

If the indexes weren't there I could probably figure it out using something like:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
if (jObject.ContainsKey("players"))
{
    var yPs = jObject["players"].ToObject<YahooPlayerListJson>();
    yPlayerList.AddRange(yPs.YPlayers);
    if(yPs.Count < 25) { f = 5000; }
}
```

but the indexes are giving me difficulty.  How do I parse this JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, this is a really terrible JSON format.  The heterogeneous arrays make it particularly difficult to work with.  It looks to me like this data was converted (badly) from XML.  If so, it might be more straightforward just to work with the XML directly.  In any case, we can make it work.  Here's the approach I would take.

1. Make some classes to capture the player data you are interested in:

   ```
   public class Player
   {
       public string PlayerKey { get; set; }
       public string PlayerId { get; set; }
       public Name Name { get; set; }
       public string EditorialPlayerKey { get; set; }
       public string EditorialTeamKey { get; set; }
       public string EditorialTeamFullName { get; set; }
       public string EditorialTeamAbbr { get; set; }
       public Week ByeWeeks { get; set; }
       public string UniformNumber { get; set; }
       public string DisplayPosition { get; set; }
       public Photo Headshot { get; set; }
       public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
       public string IsUndroppable { get; set; }
       public string PositionType { get; set; }
       public Position[] EligiblePositions { get; set; }
   }

   public class Name
   {
       public string Full { get; set; }
       public string First { get; set; }
       public string Last { get; set; }
   }

   public class Photo
   {
       public string Url { get; set; }
       public string Size { get; set; }
   }

   public class Week
   {
       [JsonProperty("week")]
       public int Number { get; set; }
   }

   public class Position
   {
       [JsonProperty("position")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Set up a serializer configured with a [`SnakeCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_SnakeCaseNamingStrategy.htm).  This will handle the translation of the `snake_case` property names in the JSON to the `ProperCase` property names in the C# classes.

   ```
   JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer
   {
       ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
       {
           NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
       }
   };
   ```
3. Parse the JSON into a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).

   ```
   string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);
   ```
4. From there use a [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) query to populate a list of `Players` as shown below.

   Here I am using [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) with a recursive-descent [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) expression as a shortcut to drill down to the `player` objects.  Each player in the JSON is actually an array containing an array of mixed content, where the content consists of some objects, containing one distinct property each, and some useless empty arrays.  So, I filter the inner array down to just the objects containing real data, and then use [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) to collect all their properties into a flat `Enumerable<JProperty>`, which I place into a temporary `JObject`.  From there I use [`ToObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1_1.htm) with the serializer configured earlier to create a new `Player` instance from the `JObject` and return the `Player` so that it is placed into the result list.

   ```
   List<Player> players =
       root.SelectTokens("$..player")
           .Select(jt =>
           {
               JObject tempObj = new JObject(
                   jt.Children<JArray>()
                     .First()
                     .Children<JObject>()
                     .SelectMany(jo => jo.Properties())
               );
               return tempObj.ToObject<Player>(serializer);
           })
           .ToList();
   ```
5. If you want to get the `count` from the JSON and compare it to the actual number of players retrieved, you can do it like this:

   ```
   int playerCount = (int)root.SelectToken("$..players.count");

   if (players.Count != playerCount)
       throw new Exception("The number of players in the list does not match the player count!");
   ```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8KYNNn

Comment: Thanks Brian,  I just got back from a short vacation.  I am excited to give this a try.  And Yes, you are correct, yahoo's default format is XML, but then they offer (terrible) json format of the same data.   Do you know of any Newtonsoft.JSON equivalent XML readers/parsers?  Either way going to give this a go in the next couple days, thanks for the detailed response.  I had gotten closer since posting the question but was still having difficulties with the arrays

Comment: Yes, if you want to deserialize XML into a class structure you can use the [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8) class; if you prefer LINQ-style queries to extract data from XML, have a look at [`XElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.8).  Both are part of the .Net framework so you don't need any extra libraries.

Comment: Amazing!  It works great!  Did not know about using Tokens that way with the naming convention ("$..player", etc).  Huge help, thank you!